# Run once for request where is the best place?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have some codes that need to run for 1 time for a request. I have a BaseController which all controllers derived from. I write my code to BaseController onActionExecuting method but it is not good because for every action execution code is running. I can prenvent it with a basic if clause but i dont want to use it like that.

What is the best place for run a code 1 time for a request. I also want to reach HttpContext where i write this code. thanks

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC a controller action is always associated with an HTTP request. So OnActionExecuting guarantees that the code executes only once per request. If this is not what you want please explain further.

Comment: This is true but not for me. Because in my views i have lots of Render.Action so that when it hit to Render.Action, BaseController.OnActionExecuting is re-run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After your comment about child actions you could test if the current action is a child action and don't execute the code. So you could have a custom action filter:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // this method happens before calling the action method

        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            // this is not the a child action => do the processing
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then decorate your base controller with this custom attribute. Similar test could be performed in the overridden [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) method of your base controller if you prefer it instead of action attributes:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        // this is not the a child action => do the processing
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: second code is better i dont want to add attributes to all my actions, thanks for your solulition.

Comment: You don't need to add attributes to all your actions. Just decorate the base controller class and it will apply to all actions and all derived controller actions.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if it is a redirect?